# Instantiating object only once upon multiple calls without using static

Tags: java, list, session

All I want is to instantiate object of list only once upon multiple calls to this servlet. Please help without the use of static keyword as it is not allowed here.

```
List<Cart> list=new ArrayList<Cart>();

        list.add(new Cart(name, cost));


        HttpSession s=req.getSession();
        s.setAttribute("list",list);
        out.println("item successfully added to cart");
        out.println("\n<a href=\'viewserv\'>view cart</a>");
        out.println("\n<a href=\'item\'>view item</a>");
```

Comment: Please clarify. I have no idea what you are asking for.

Comment: @AlexandreSantos the poster mentions a servlet. Would singletons survive across sessions? A cache object might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

As you are storing that into session, You need to just check it weather it is there in session already or not .

```
   HttpSession s=req.getSession();
   if(s.getAttribute("list") !=null){
   sessionList =new ArrayList<Cart>();/create new   
   }else { 
   sessionList = (List)s.getAttribute("list");
   sessionList.add(....
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want the same object to persist across all HTTP requests served by this servlet.

Simply make this object as the instance variable of your servlet and instantiate it in servlet's init method.

Answer (score 0):

> I want is to instantiate object of list only once upon multiple calls
>   of servlet

You should initialize the `List` on `init` method of `Servlet`.

```
List<Cart> list=null;

@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {//This method will call only once
   list=Collections.syncronizedList(new ArrayList<Cart>());
}
```

Please note that, the above declaration must care about synchronization.

Comment: It seems the list for user session specific.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ, May be. But OP didn't mentioned that.